# UIAlertControllerでボタンを押すと非表示にするには？

Tags: swift

お世話になります。
UIAlertControllerで、ボタンを押した時、それ以降アラートを非表示にするにはどうしたら良いですか？
一応、下記のコードを使用するつもりです。

```
let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title:"注意！",
                                                        message: "まず最初に登録を行って下さい。",
                                                        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        //Cancel 一つだけしか指定できない
        let cancelAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "以降表示しない",
                                                       style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel,
                                                       handler:{
                                                        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                                                        print("非表示")
        })

        //Destructive 複数指定可
        let destructiveAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK!",
                                                            style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive,
                                                            handler:{
                                                                (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                                                                print("OK!")
        })

        //AlertもActionSheetも同じ
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(destructiveAction)


        //表示。UIAlertControllerはUIViewControllerを継承している。
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いい方法かわわかりませんが、カウントしてif文とかで分けるのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。